# How to send rendered html file through email in java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to burst the report and send it through email but my html file contains .js,.css and many libraries,How can I send the rendered Html for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe include all the scripts style's and import in the . That would give a single file displaying the whole page, if that's what you want.

Comment: It includes different API also.